# Create Wrapper class for google analytics in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-analytics

I am using google analytics service in my Application to track the screen view and events like button pressing. But for code reusability i want to create a WRAPPER CLASS for it. Please tell me how to do that !

Code for tracking events like button press :-

```
-(void)logButtonPress:(UIButton *)button{

    id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];

    [tracker set:kGAIScreenName value:@"Google Analytics"];
    [tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createEventWithCategory:@"UX"
                                                          action:@"touch"
                                                           label:[button.titleLabel text]
                                                           value:nil] build]];
    [tracker set:kGAIScreenName value:nil];
}
```

Code for page view :-

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];
    [tracker set:kGAIScreenName value:@"Google Analytics"];
    [tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createScreenView] build]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this `GTrack`
https://github.com/gemr/GTrack

Manual Screen Tracking

```
- (void)viewDidAppear {
    [super viewDidAppear];

    [[GTTracker sharedInstance] sendScreenEventWithTitle:@"Your Screen Name Here"];
}
```

Sending Events

```
[[GTTracker sharedInstance] sendAnalyticsEventWithCategory:@"Your Category" action:@"Your Action" label:@"Your Label" value:@(yourValue)];
[[GTTracker sharedInstance] sendAnalyticsEventWithCategory:@"Your Category" action:@"Your Action" label:@"Your Label"];
[[GTTracker sharedInstance] sendAnalyticsEventWithCategory:@"Your Category" action:@"Your Action"];
[[GTTracker sharedInstance] sendAnalyticsEventWithCategory:@"Your Category"];
```

Comment: we cannot send event directly like this, we have to initialize the tracker everytime :-  id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];

Comment: Why ? You need only on singleton to do all tasks about analytics.